# PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager from Glassfish EJB module

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, netbeans, glassfish

This EJB module is aimed at moving the database connection from the client to server-side to [improve the connection and overall structure](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/62890/15315).  I copied the same `persistence.xml` file over, and added, from Netbeans, EclipseLink from Glassfish for the JPA connection.

Why isn't the EJB module picking up the persistence.xml file?

tree of the clean project:

```
LegacyEJB/
├── build.xml
├── nbproject
│   ├── ant-deploy.xml
│   ├── build-impl.xml
│   ├── genfiles.properties
│   ├── private
│   │   └── private.properties
│   ├── project.properties
│   └── project.xml
├── setup
│   └── glassfish-resources.xml
└── src
    ├── conf
    │   ├── MANIFEST.MF
    │   └── persistence.xml
    └── java
        ├── META-INF
        │   └── persistence.xml
        └── net
            └── bounceme
                └── dur
                    ├── db
                    │   ├── Clients.java
                    │   ├── Criteria.java
                    │   ├── DatabaseConnection.java
                    │   ├── MyProps.java
                    │   ├── User.java
                    │   └── UserRole.java
                    └── legacy
                        └── ejb
                            └── LegacySession.java
```

glassfish stacktrace:

```
INFO:   visiting unvisited references
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB LegacySession: [java:global/LegacyEJB/LegacySession!net.bounceme.dur.legacy.LegacySessionRemote, java:global/LegacyEJB/LegacySession]
INFO:   EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB LegacySession: [net.bounceme.dur.legacy.LegacySessionRemote#net.bounceme.dur.legacy.LegacySessionRemote, net.bounceme.dur.legacy.LegacySessionRemote]
INFO:   LegacyEJB was successfully deployed in 1,409 milliseconds.
INFO:   visiting unvisited references
INFO:   visiting unvisited references
INFO:   ACDEPL103: Java Web Start services started for the app client LegacyApplication (contextRoot: /LegacyApplication)
INFO:   LegacyApplication was successfully deployed in 264 milliseconds.
INFO:   query db
WARNING:   EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB LegacySession, method: public java.util.List net.bounceme.dur.legacy.ejb.LegacySession.getAll()
WARNING:   javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy368.getAll(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:143)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:173)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named LegacyDatabasePU
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at net.bounceme.dur.db.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:23)
    at net.bounceme.dur.db.DatabaseConnection.findAll(DatabaseConnection.java:30)
    at net.bounceme.dur.legacy.ejb.LegacySession.getAll(LegacySession.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:205)
    ... 19 more
```

database connection:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.db;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

public enum DatabaseConnection {

    INSTANCE;
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DatabaseConnection.class.getName());

    private EntityManager connect() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("LegacyDatabasePU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        log.fine("" + em.isOpen());
        return em;
    }

    public List<Clients> findAll() {
        EntityManager em = connect();
        Query q = em.createQuery("select c from Clients c");
        List<Clients> clients = q.getResultList();
        em.close();
        return clients;
    }

    public List<Clients> selectByCriteria(Criteria criteria) {
        log.info(criteria.toString());
        EntityManager em = connect();
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Clients> clientCriteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Clients.class);
        Root<Clients> clientRoot = clientCriteriaQuery.from(Clients.class);
        clientCriteriaQuery.select(clientRoot);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.name), "%" + criteria.getName() + "%"));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.phone1), "%" + criteria.getPhone1() + "%"));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.email), "%" + criteria.getEmail() + "%"));
        if (!criteria.getOpener().equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.opener), "%" + criteria.getOpener() + "%"));
        }
        if (!criteria.getCloser1().equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.closer1), "%" + criteria.getCloser1() + "%"));
        }
        if (!criteria.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.status), "%" + criteria.getStatus() + "%"));
        }
        clientCriteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        List<Clients> clients = em.createQuery(clientCriteriaQuery).getResultList();
        em.close();
        return clients;
    }

    public Clients findById(int id) {
        EntityManager em = connect();
        Clients client = em.find(Clients.class, id);
        em.close();
        return client;
    }

    public void send(int id) {
        EntityManager em = connect();
        Clients c = em.find(Clients.class, id);
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        Timestamp t = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        c.setDateUpdated(t.toString());
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }

    private Timestamp stamp() {
        Date d = new Date();
        return new Timestamp(d.getTime());
    }

    public int persistClient(Clients client) {
        EntityManager em = connect();
        client.setDateCreated(stamp().toString());
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(client);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        log.fine(client.getTrim());
        em.close();
        return client.getId();
    }

    public int update(Clients newClient) {
        EntityManager em = connect();
        Clients oldClient = em.find(Clients.class, newClient.getId());
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        oldClient.setAddress(newClient.getAddress());
        oldClient.setCity(newClient.getCity());
    //omitted for brevity
        oldClient.setVerifier(newClient.getVerifier());
        oldClient.setYear(newClient.getYear());
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        return newClient.getId();
    }
}
```

persistence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="LegacyDatabasePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>legacy.database.Clients</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/legacy?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="jdbc"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

project.properties for the JAR's on the classpath:

```
annotation.processing.enabled=true
annotation.processing.enabled.in.editor=true
annotation.processing.processor.options=-Aeclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory=false
annotation.processing.processors.list=
annotation.processing.run.all.processors=true
annotation.processing.source.output=${build.generated.sources.dir}/ap-source-output
build.classes.dir=${build.dir}/classes
build.classes.excludes=**/*.java,**/*.form,**/.nbattrs
build.dir=build
build.ear.classes.dir=${build.dir}/classes
build.generated.dir=${build.dir}/generated
build.generated.sources.dir=${build.dir}/generated-sources
build.test.classes.dir=${build.dir}/test/classes
build.test.results.dir=${build.dir}/test/results
debug.classpath=${javac.classpath}:${build.classes.dir}
debug.test.classpath=\
    ${run.test.classpath}
dist.dir=dist
dist.ear.jar=${dist.dir}/${jar.name}
dist.jar=${dist.dir}/${jar.name}
dist.javadoc.dir=${dist.dir}/javadoc
endorsed.classpath=\
    ${libs.javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.classpath}
excludes=
includes=**
j2ee.compile.on.save=false
j2ee.deploy.on.save=false
j2ee.platform=1.7
j2ee.platform.classpath=${j2ee.server.middleware}/mq/lib/jaxm-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/javax.annotation-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/webservices-api-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/jaxb-api-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.websocket-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.ws.rs-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/bean-validator.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/webservices-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.xml.registry-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.enterprise.concurrent.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.transaction-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.enterprise.deploy-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.servlet.jsp-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.management.j2ee-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/weld-osgi-bundle.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.interceptor-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.json.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.ejb-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.resource-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.servlet-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.servlet.jsp.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/jaxb-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.inject.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.security.jacc-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.batch-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.xml.rpc-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.jms-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.enterprise.concurrent-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.faces.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.persistence.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.security.auth.message-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.mail.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.el.jar
j2ee.platform.embeddableejb.classpath=${j2ee.server.home}/lib/embedded/glassfish-embedded-static-shell.jar
j2ee.platform.wscompile.classpath=${j2ee.server.home}/modules/webservices-osgi.jar
j2ee.platform.wsgen.classpath=${j2ee.server.home}/modules/webservices-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/webservices-api-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/jaxb-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/jaxb-api-osgi.jar
j2ee.platform.wsimport.classpath=${j2ee.server.home}/modules/webservices-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/webservices-api-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/jaxb-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/jaxb-api-osgi.jar
j2ee.platform.wsit.classpath=
j2ee.server.type=gfv3ee6
jar.compress=false
jar.name=LegacyEJB.jar
jars.in.ejbjar=false
javac.classpath=\
    ${reference.LegacyLibrary.jar}:\
    ${libs.EclipseLink-GlassFish-v3.classpath}
javac.debug=true
javac.deprecation=false
javac.processorpath=\
    ${javac.classpath}:\
    ${libs.eclipselink.classpath}:\
    ${libs.eclipselinkmodelgen.classpath}
javac.source=1.7
javac.target=1.7
javac.test.classpath=\
    ${javac.classpath}:\
    ${build.classes.dir}
javac.test.processorpath=${javac.test.classpath}
javadoc.additionalparam=
javadoc.author=false
javadoc.encoding=${source.encoding}
javadoc.noindex=false
javadoc.nonavbar=false
javadoc.notree=false
javadoc.preview=true
javadoc.private=false
javadoc.splitindex=true
javadoc.use=true
javadoc.version=false
javadoc.windowtitle=
meta.inf=${source.root}/conf
meta.inf.excludes=sun-cmp-mappings.xml
platform.active=default_platform
project.LegacyLibrary=../LegacyLibrary
reference.LegacyLibrary.jar=${project.LegacyLibrary}/dist/LegacyLibrary.jar
resource.dir=setup
run.test.classpath=\
    ${javac.test.classpath}:\
    ${build.test.classes.dir}
# Space-separated list of JVM arguments used when running a class with a main method or a unit test
# (you may also define separate properties like run-sys-prop.name=value instead of -Dname=value):
runmain.jvmargs=
source.encoding=UTF-8
source.root=src
src.dir=${source.root}/java
test.src.dir=test
```

Comment: Usually in Java EE, the datasources (JDBC connections) are managed by the server and set up in the server configuration, providing a datasource to the `persistence.xml` via JNDI only.  I'm not sure whether using a client `persistence.xml` like in above example is valid in the container (and might be the source of errors here).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/doc.1111/e25034/tlandgs.htm#CIHJGIEF  something like that?  it's a persistence.xml file on glassfish...or is that just the wrong approach?  Why is the above a *client* `persistence.xml` versus **server**?

Comment: yes, like in that link.  In your `persistence.xml`, you configure a direct JDBC connection via properties, as opposed to the `<jta-data-source>jdbc/bvcallbackbmt</jta-data-source>` in your linked example.

Comment: You don't even need to specify the `<provider>` tag (the container provides it), the `<jta-data-source>` and possibly the `<class>` lines suffice.  Then configure the datasource in glassfish (where you can also test the connection indepentently of your application).

Comment: I don't really find much mention of actually using `persistence.xml` from *within* glassfish itself -- most links seem to be about copying the driver into the lib folder.  what is the scenario which calls for a `persistence.xml` file?

Comment: Not sure, what you mean, but without a `persistence.xml` in your EJBś  `META-INF`, no persistence unit is created/provided by the container.  Therefore, if you want to use JPA, you'll need to add a `persistence.xml`.